# Bulk Insert Incorrect Syntax Near 'FORMAT'

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error, sql-server-2016, bulkinsert

I am trying to import a `.CSV` file into a table in SQL Server. It seems like a pretty straight forward process, however, I get an error when running the query:

> Incorrect syntax near 'FORMAT'

Here is the query:

```sql
--import file
BULK INSERT dbo.ADDRESSSCHEDULE_Backup
FROM 'C:\Users\azenk\Desktop\SQL\Exports\AddressSchedule.csv'
WITH
(
    FORMAT = 'CSV',
    FIRSTROW = 2
)
```

I tried to do a bulk insert. I did not get any warnings before running the query so I expect the rows from my CSV to be imported to the specified table.

Comment: I assume you are using an older version of SQL Server (you've not tagged your version here, so I can only guess). If you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#format--csv) you'll see it's only in 2017+. That syntax *is* valid in SQL Server 2017+.

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry. I should have included that. I am running MS SQL Server 2016. Is it possible to do this Bulk Insert with a change to the syntax?

Comment: Remove the `FORMAT` parameter and define your `FIELDTERMINATOR`. Though if you are using quote-identified values, you won't get the results you expect. In that eventuality you'll need to use *something else* or change your CSV files to not be quote identified and use a delimiter that doesn't appear in your data.

Comment: @azenk Not really, because prior to 2017 SQL Server never supported RFC-style CSV files, bulk insert files were a special (binary?) format with (laughably) no way of escaping certain character sequences, making it impractical for use anyway, unless you're interoping with some legacy _big iron_ IBM system and actually using ASCII data separator characters as-intended I guess...

Comment: You could look at using `OpenRowset` and the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` driver; combined with a *schema.ini* file you have a reasonable amount of control over the file, delimters, text qualifier, character encoding etc.

Comment: If you need to read in RFC 4180-style delimited files, where field data may contain line breaks, delimiters (e.g.: commas) or text qualifiers (e.g.: quotes), then you basically can't do that using `BULK INSERT` on anything earlier than SQL Server 2017. The external [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) will not help you here, either, because 18 years later it still doesn't support RFC 4180-style files. There are other external options, though, such as using PowerShell's `Import-Csv` cmdlet in conjunction with the `SqlBulkCopy` class.